# Please help identifying this SOT-23 part from a vehicle sensor

Tags: components, hall-effect

What is this encircled part in the picture? It is labeled "WB2" and "62".

This is a vehicle sensor.

[image: Photo of the sensor with the component marked]

Comment: says here  zener 3.6V http://www.s-manuals.com/smd/wb but I can't find that in the datasheet.

Comment: @Jasen look for marking code *B2 https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BZX84_SER.pdf

Comment: `* = placeholder for manufacturing site code` thanks

Comment: thanks.thanks all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NXP     BZX84-C3V6

3.6V zener diode

https://nz.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/MMBZ5221BLT1-D-1292992.pdf